# How to position the footer links in magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, magento-community, footer-links

I want to remove the links in footer (below company, connect with us block) & move the newsletter block above the footer block in magento1.9 from below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to  `app/design/frontend/[yourpackage]/[yourtheme]/page/html/footer.phtml` and remove footer (below company, connect with us block).

you have created CMS block named 'footer_data' from admin panel. Then following will be code to call them in `footer.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_data')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

OR

you using **rdw**, theme go to Static Blocks and edit **"Footer Links SM"** and **"Footer Links Company"**.

For **newsletter**  go to page `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml`

and change it(remove html).
Using xml Go to `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/newsletter.xml` and comment `<default>..` tag.

i hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you.Edited "Footer Links SM" and "Footer Links Company"

Comment: but how to move newsletter block above footer block?

Comment: @Ramya : I edited my answer .

Comment: what should I change in subscribe.phtml?

Comment: do you have remove newsletter or need change ?

Comment: i just want to change its position above footer block.

Comment: you can change it to footer block ,but you have to use staick value like form url, title, label name, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For company links to remove or edit by default in magento Rwd theme from backend admin panel we get a option of **Footer Company links**.

Inside `CMS -> static block -> Footer Company links`

Answer (score 0):

Check In the `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/page/html/footer.phtml`
go to above file and check where you find cms block for this section and login in admin panel go to cms-block and find that particular cms block and change it.
 or in footer.phtml file just comment below cms block line 
`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('social-media')->toHtml(); ?>`